# WOL from Windows works, etherwake from debian doesn't

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wake-on-lan

I have an EdgeRouter. It's basically a Debian OS device. When I send a command etherwake -D XX:XX.... it says `Sendto worked ! 116.`. But nothing happens. The target machine stays off.

Now I use this basic 'Wake On LAN' app from the microsoft store and it wakes the device immediately.

What's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried `wakeonlan` package and command simply like this: `wakeonlan 00:1D:72:27:5F:XX`?

Comment: Yes. I got another laptop running ubuntu and did the same. I did both wakeonlan and etherwake. I gave them 5 minutes, nothing is happening. Now I use this WOL from win10 store, in it's up in 3 seconds

Comment: Hey @LinuxSecurityFreak, your comment got me closer to the problem. etherwake gives no other info except to input the HW mac. The wakeonlan package says a lot of things and I figured that it was using the wrong broadcast address

Comment: I'm happy to help anytime! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm a genius. WOL from Microsoft Store works because it knows my IP and stuff. The wakeonlan uses default broadcast port 255.255.255.255 which is incorrect since I'm on a 192.168.1.*/24.

I changed command to `wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 -p 9 <HW Mac here>` and it worked.

```
Usage
    wakeonlan [-h] [-v] [-i IP_address] [-p port] [-f file] [[hardware_address] ...]

Options
    -h
        this information
    -v
        displays the script version
    -i ip_address
        set the destination IP address
        default: 255.255.255.255 (the limited broadcast address)
    -p port
        set the destination port
        default: 9 (the discard port)
    -f file
        uses file as a source of hardware addresses

See also
    wakeonlan(1)
```